# Can android developers use the kindle fire to run their apps?

Tags: usb-debugging, amazon-kindle

I need a device to test my application against but don't own an android device. I found the Kindle fire for $40 which seamed like a great deal to get me started debugging my app but it says it uses their custom 'FireOS'. I was wondering if I could still use the kindle to debug my app because if not I will not purchase it.

Comment: Why not Android Emulator?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. @SarpSTA some developers (including me) prefer to use real hardware, because of performance and usability reasons (testing real usage conditions etc.).

Comment: @GiantTree also the fact that the android emulator doesn't have the best support for OpenGL ES

Comment: You could use it to debut your app as long as you don't use any Google-specific APIs, as the FireOS is a custom version of Android with Amazon's ecosystem in it while not including the all-common GApps. You could potentially root it and it install a GApps package to get around this, however.

Comment: Also, don't ask which device to use for debugging, as hardware recommendations are off-topic here. //The ideal device would be a Nexus.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury when did I ask for hardware recommendations?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury could you resubmit your reply as an answer so I can accept it. Just in case someone finds thist post while googling a similar problem.

Comment: That was a preventive measure, just in case you did end up asking for the right hardware for the job. That question would be a fit for Hardware Recommendations SE, not AE

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury ok I understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why it isn't a good idea

The Kindle Fire runs Amazon's customized version of Android, namely, FireOS.

FireOS has a very tight integration with Amazon's content distribution platform (Amazon's ecosystem, so to say) at the cost of the traditional Google integration we normally find in Android devices.

This is to say, Amazon devices, although they run Android, lack any Google Apps as default or installable from the Amazon AppStore. It is possible to root a Kindle Fire tablet and flash a GApps package, but that (IIRC) is a probable violation of Amazon's Terms of Service, so I will not include that information here. It can be found with a simple search, however.

## TL;DR

*How is this relevant to an app developer looking at a Kindle to test their apps?*

1. If your app only relies on APIs provided by "core" Android, AOSP, there's no problem. Your app can successfully be used on Kindle Fire, and hence tested on it.
2. If your app relies on anything Google provides as OEM stock on most Android devices, such as Maps, Play Services or Play Games, your app won't run at all due to missing library dependencies, unless you have hacked the Kindle Fire and installed the core GApps onto it after rooting, flashing a custom recovery or ROM, etc.
3. If your app relies on Amazon Services, well, you should be using the Kindle Fire for testing. It is Amazon's product and will work best with it.

Finally, most Android developers do consider a Nexus as "the" device for Android app development and testing, but opinions differ, and you should decide your testing decice requirements on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score -1):

If your app is for android, you can use the android emulator what google offers to developers. The Amazon Kindle how **Tamoghna**  says, runs a limited and custom system of Android.

If you cant run the google emulator you can try the [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) what offers to the users free virtual machines with android. Also offers a premium service to custom and more android versions.

*The free version* let you test and develop on the more common devices.

Comment: The emulator has been suggested to the OP, and he has clearly indicated that he is not interested in an emulator for the purpose, but only in real hardware. If you indeed wish to suggest an emulator, why not VirtualBox, VMWARE, BlueStacks, etc. etc. Is a problem. I suggest that you remove this irrelevant answer.

Comment: And the "virtual machines" you refer to are not even a bit like real common devices, e.g. the virtual machines have x86 processors like their host machine, unlike most Android devices which have ARM. This answer is riddled with misconceptions. I'm sorry. -1